# Vue.js app no errors but white page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to learn Vue. 
I read this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/fetching-data-third-party-api-vue-axios/) and I'm trying to split it in single file components using the standard vue-cli webpack template. I don't have any error in console but the page is white, and I cannot understand why.

This is my main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
window.axios = require('axios');

const NYTBaseUrl = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/";
const ApiKey = "18e1540d187c4b46bae767782750f9fd";
const SECTIONS = "home, arts, automobiles, books, business, fashion, food, health, insider, magazine, movies, national, nyregion, obituaries, opinion, politics, realestate, science, sports, sundayreview, technology, theater, tmagazine, travel, upshot, world";

function buildUrl (url) {
  return NYTBaseUrl + url + ".json?api-key=" + ApiKey
}

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    results: [],
    sections: SECTIONS.split(', '), // create an array of the sections
    section: 'home', // set default section to 'home'
    loading: true,
    title: ''
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getPosts('home');
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts(section) {
      let url = buildUrl(section);
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.results = response.data.results;
        let title = this.section !== 'home' ? "Top stories in '"+ this.section + "' today" : "Top stories today";
        this.title = title + "(" + response.data.num_results+ ")";
      }).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
    }
  }
});
```

And this is the App.vue file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <product-list></product-list>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Products from './components/Products'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Products
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="sass" >
  @import '~bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass'
  @import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all"
  @import "~bulma/sass/base/_all"
  @import "~bulma/sass/grid/columns"
  @import "~bulma/sass/components/_all"
</style>
```

I also create a Products.vue file in the components folder

```
<template id="product-list">
  <section>
    <div class="row" v-for="posts in processedPosts">
      <div class="columns large-3 medium-6" v-for="post in posts">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-divider">
        {{ post.title }}
        </div>
        <a :href="post.url" target="_blank"><img :src="post.image_url"></a>
        <div class="card-section">
          <p>{{ post.abstract }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</template>

Vue.component('Products', {
  props: ['results'],
  template: "#product-list",
  computed: {
    processedPosts() {
      let posts = this.results;

      // Add image_url attribute
      posts.map(post => {
        let imgObj = post.multimedia.find(media => media.format === "superJumbo");
        post.image_url = imgObj ? imgObj.url : "http://placehold.it/300x200?text=N/A";
      });

      // Put Array into Chunks
      let i, j, chunkedArray = [],
        chunk = 4;
      for (i = 0, j = 0; i < posts.length; i += chunk, j++) {
        chunkedArray[j] = posts.slice(i, i + chunk);
      }
      return chunkedArray;
    }
  }
});
```

Everything looks fine for me (except for the `window.axios = require('axios');` that I don't understand why is not present in the original tutorial) but the page is blank and also the  tag I add for debug is not present in the DOM.

**Edit**

Looks like the code is not compiled.

My page source code is

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

** Edit 2 **

I understand the problem. This is my index.html.

Comment: Have you checked browser console, there should be some error, if it's a blank page, also on your `Products.vue` file javascript is not wrapped in a script tag, that could cause error, webpack would throw error on situation like this, and everything will stop working.

Comment: @azs06 no errors, just "Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools". And the server "DONE  Compiled successfully in 5015ms"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several issues with your codes. First you have to wrap JavaScript in a `script` tag on your `Products.vue` file. Also on your `Products.vue` file you could just export the component files instead of creating the way you did, also you haven't imported `Vue` on `Products.vue` file but you are using it `Vue.component('Products', {})`. You should create `Products.vue` file this way

`Products.vue`

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="container" v-for="posts in processedPosts">
      <div class="columns" v-for="post in posts">
        <div class="column is-6 is-offset-3">
           <div class="card">
           <header class="card-header">
             <p class="card-header-title">
            {{ post.title }}
            </p>
           </header>
           <div class="card-image">
           <a :href="post.url" target="_blank">
             <figure class="image">
               <img :src="post.image_url">
             </figure>
           </a>
           </div>

        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="content">
            <p>{{ post.abstract }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</template>
<script>
export default{
  props: ['results'],
  computed: {
    processedPosts() {
      let posts = this.results;
      // Add image_url attribute
      posts.map(post => {
        let imgObj = post.multimedia.find(media => media.format === "superJumbo");
        post.image_url = imgObj ? imgObj.url : "http://placehold.it/300x200?text=N/A";
      });

      // Put Array into Chunks
      let i, j, chunkedArray = [],
        chunk = 4;
      for (i = 0, j = 0; i < posts.length; i += chunk, j++) {
        chunkedArray[j] = posts.slice(i, i + chunk);
      }
      return chunkedArray;
    }
  }  
}
</script>
```

On your `main.js` file you forgot to mount `<App />` template.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
})
```

You should also move code for network request, components to `App.vue` file.

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
window.axios = require('axios');

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
})
```

Have to use the component we are importing, on your code you imported `Products` but using `<product-list></product-list>`.

`App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <products :results="results"></products>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Products from './components/Products'

const NYTBaseUrl = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/";
const ApiKey = "18e1540d187c4b46bae767782750f9fd";
const SECTIONS = "home, arts, automobiles, books, business, fashion, food, health, insider, magazine, movies, national, nyregion, obituaries, opinion, politics, realestate, science, sports, sundayreview, technology, theater, tmagazine, travel, upshot, world";

function buildUrl (url) {
  return NYTBaseUrl + url + ".json?api-key=" + ApiKey
}

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: function(){
    return {
    results: [],
    sections: SECTIONS.split(', '), // create an array of the sections
    section: 'home', // set default section to 'home'
    loading: true,
    title: ''
    }
  },
  components: {
    Products
  },
  mounted(){
    this.getPosts('home');
  },
  methods:{
    getPosts(section) {
      let url = buildUrl(section);
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.results = response.data.results;
        let title = this.section !== 'home' ? "Top stories in '"+ this.section + "' today" : "Top stories today";
        this.title = title + "(" + response.data.num_results+ ")";
      }).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
    }    
  }
}
</script>
```

I tested this out, and uploaded code to github https://github.com/azs06/vuejs-news, you can clone it and check it out. Here it is deployed http://noisy-coach.surge.sh/

**Note:** I am using the api key temporarily will remove it, as soon as you test it out.

Comment: Thank you so much... I understand now!

Answer (score -2):

Next time to debug your code - first you should take a look at browser console for errors.

You can see full code of this tutorial here - https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/vuejs-news
Just make sure you write code like it's shown on github files.

Comment: No errors in browser console! I fix them, for example Axios not defined